# Binary Request Body in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How Can i set image from imageview in binary body in API endpoint?

I need to get image from an ImageView and put it into a request body that expects a binary value (jpg image)
How can I do the bellow API calling in kotlin?

[This is the call in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joW3O.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough context in your question, eg example code. But try the below:

```
//get drawable from your imageview
Drawabel drawable = imageVIew.getDrawable();
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable);

//convert image to binary
Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte);
```

`byte[] imageInByte` is what you asked for, but I have also added conversion to stream in case you end up needing that.

Comment: I did convert the ImageView to byte[], but I need to put it inside the endpoint calling, and I keep getting error.

Comment: @LucasPenna show the code that is sending the byte[]. Also, is the back-end API end point proven to work? Or is it also new. If it is new then you may need to show its code, so others can help more.

Comment: I did edit the question and put an image from postman.
The endpoint is not new, it's working, but my problem is how to call it from kotlin code